# Building up a string using a list of values

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to fill in a string with a specific format in mind. When I have a single value, it's easy to build it:

```
>>> x = "there are {} {} on the table.".format('3', 'books')
>>> x
'there are 3 books on the table.'
```

but what if I have a long list of objects

```
items =[{'num':3, 'obj':'books'}, {'num':1, 'obj':'pen'},...]
```

and I want to construct the sentence in the exact same way:

```
There are 3 books and 1 pen and 2 cellphones and... on the table
```

How would I be able to do that, given that I don't know the length of the list? Using `format` I could easily construct the string, but then I have to know the length of the list beforehand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`str.join()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)<sup>*</sup> to build up the objects part:

```
objects = ' and '.join(['{num} {obj}'.format(**item) for item in items])
```

then interpolate that into the full sentence:

```
x = "There are {} on the table".format(objects)
```

Demo:

```
>>> items = [{'num': 3, 'obj': 'books'}, {'num': 1, 'obj': 'pen'}, {'num': 2, 'obj': 'cellphones'}]
>>> objects = ' and '.join(['{num} {obj}'.format(**item) for item in items])
>>> "There are {} on the table".format(objects)
'There are 3 books and 1 pen and 2 cellphones on the table'
```

---

<sup>*</sup> You *could* use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), but for a `str.join()` call [a list comprehension happens to be faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/100297).

Comment: Martijn, why a list comprehension and not a generator expressions as the parameter to `str.join`?

Comment: @Robᵩ Because `join` will convert the generator expression to list by itself.And by passing the generator expression to join you will force the `join` to does this job!

Comment: @Robᵩ: I always am asked this, and I always edit in the link to Raymond's exposé as to how it is faster to use a list comp.